# Node.js 16.x on Debian 11, "supported" or "not supported"

Tags: node.js, debian, bullseye

As I seem to have run into a deadlock, has anyone found the way out of this maze?

Installing `nodejs 16.x` on `Debian 11`:

With: `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x`

Starts off with:
`Confirming "bullseye" is supported...`

And then gives up, with:
`Your distribution, identified as "bullseye", is not currently supported`

/etc/debian_version = 11.7

The procedure is described in many sources. All seem to follow the same setup as this: https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-debian-11-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a version manager with nodejs. This will allow you to install node 16 as well as other versions in parallel and switch between them at your pleasure. I use fnm: https://github.com/Schniz/fnm. Another one that has been around for a while is nvm: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. With fnm installed you can then do:

```
fnm install 16
```

Check the specific documentation if you decide to use another version manager.